# problem with redirecting

Tags: apache-2.2, dyndns

I have something like this `myhost.dyndns.org`. When I put `myhost.dyndns.org` in browser then redirect me to ADSL modem IP (10.0.0.138) but I try to redirect me on localhost (Apache server). How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You must set a port forward on your router/modem at least for port 80 to the (local) IP for your server.

Beware, this can be dangerous as anyone can access this website in your private network.

Comment: How to do this? You mean set NAPT?

Comment: Depending on your setup, something like NAPT might be available for you. In most cases though, you will have to look for something called port forward or a variant thereof. Actually, NAPT is a combination of normal NAT and port forwarding, if I remember this correctly.

Comment: Check out http://portforward.com/